# How to add values to a mySQL database with JSON and AJAX?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, json

Currently blank rows are being entered into my mySQL database. Undefined index is what I'm getting for Name and Address in the PHP. I'm using the javaScript code as part of a function. The user will activate this function and this adding to the database will happen seemless behind the scenes.

How can I get the values to enter the mySQL.

PHP Code,

```
<?php
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "pass", "db");

$name = $_POST['Name']; 
$address = $_POST['Address'];

mysqli_query($connection,"INSERT INTO offerSelected (Id, Url) VALUES ('".$name."','".$address."')");
?>
```

JavaScript

```
var name = "John";
var address = "UK";

var sendInfo = {
Name: name,
Address: address
};

var params = JSON.stringify(sendInfo);
alert(params);

var httpSend = new XMLHttpRequest();
var php = "http://server/~name/folder/insertOffer.php";
httpSend.open("POST", php, true);

httpSend.onreadystatechange = function()
{
if(httpSend.readyState == 4 && httpSend.status == 200) {
    alert("sent");

}
}

httpSend.send(params);
```

UPDATED

```
var params = 'Name=' + name + '&Address=' + address;
alert(params);

var httpSend = new XMLHttpRequest();
var php = "http://server/~name/folder/insertOffer.php";
httpSend.open("POST", php, true);

httpSend.onreadystatechange = function()
{
if(httpSend.readyState == 4 && httpSend.status == 200) {
    alert("h");

}
}

httpSend.send(params);
```

Comment: Please don't use raw user input in your SQL. It's [open to SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com)

Comment: What does your HTML look like? `Undefined index` is sometimes indicative of mis-matching HTML form element names.

Comment: There is no relative html to this. This javaScript is going to be a function which is activated by a user with an onclick button and this adding to the database is going to happen seamless to the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from the SQL injection problems people mentioned in the comments, the problem with your code is `JSON.stringify`. The POST parameters use a key-value format just like GET requests, which means your params should look like this:

```
Name=name&Address=address
```

And not a JSON object. You also have to add this line of code after `httpSend.open` to tell the server that you are sending key/values:

```
httpSend.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

Comment: I achieved what you said but my PHP is incorrect? I'm not receiving my values correctly

Comment: @moss Could you elaborate?

Comment: I updated my javaScript code above so my code now sends Name=name&Address=address like you said. However my php still gives back Undefined indexes.. I'm not sure how to extract the data.